# Among all unit vectors $\vec{u}=\scriptsize\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^3$ which one minimizes the sum $x+2y+3z$?

Tags: linear-algebra, orthonormal, orthogonality

My first instinct, of course, was to use Lagrange multipliers, but I have to use linear algebra to solve this.

How would I construct an orthonormal basis in this case? I'm not sure how to parametrize the span of vectors. Should I use Cauchy-Schwarz, or the fact that $\theta=\text{arccos}\frac{\vec{x}\cdot\vec{y}}{||\vec{x}||\,||\vec{y}||}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**hint**: $$(x+2y+3z)^2 \leq (1^2+2^2+3^2)(x^2+y^2+z^2)$$ by CS inequality.

Comment: CS implies $x+2y+3z\leq (\sqrt{14})(\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2})$. But how do I express this boundary in components?

Comment: $=$ sign occurs when $\dfrac{1}{x} = \dfrac{2}{y} = \dfrac{3}{z}$

Comment: @BenjaminLoya More relevantly, you get $-\sqrt{14} \le x+2y+3z$ with equality condition as above.